# How do I send multiple transactions from one wallet in Nodejs?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, javascript, nodejs, wallet-transfer

Hi I've been reading around and I came across Web3.js

It's not apparent to me how I can send Ether from one wallet to multiple recipients other than in a batch-style request (which inevitably takes a lot of time and is prone to failure)

I see people suggesting contracts but almost 9/10 of the posts I read were referring to ERC20 tokens but I am looking to send just plain ol' Ether.

I have a website where people are going to be earning Ethers and all types of cryptos and the amount they earn is stored in a MongoDB database,

For Monero, I just pull the values the earn from the MongoDB database and push them into an array. I wait for the array to be filled with Promises and then I execute the function with an array, and Monero Wallet RPC knows that its an array and sends all the transactions out as one big payment.

How do I do something similar in Ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a smart contract to fulfill your purpose.

A short pseudo example:

```
// example code - proceed with cation before using on the mainnet!!!

function batchEtherSend(uint256[] amounts, address[] receipents) payable public {
    require(amounts.length == receipents.length, "invalid params");

    // for loop 
        if(addresses[i] != address(0)) { // check for valid address 
            addresses[i].transfer(amounts[i]); // note transfer will revert if any one fails
        }

}
```

Comment: this example is for solidity or web3js?

Comment: This would be in Solidity as it's a smart contract.
If this were in web3.js it would represent multiple transactions, not one. Which is what you wanted to avoid.